# Cannot convert form Service to annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, service

I have a class and i want to annotate it as a service. What i did is:

```
@Service
public class PaymentInTermsServiceImpl implements PaymentInTermsService {
@Override
public SOAPMessage createSOAPMessage(String clientNumber, OrderData order, String accUrl, String refUrl, String rejUrl) throws SOAPException 
{
```

Now Eclipse gives an error saying: "Cannot convert form service to annotation"
I have this in my frontend-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Scan for annotation configured controller -->
<context:component-scan base-package="frontend.web.*"/>
```

Comment: Show us the whole stack trace, not just a fragment of the error message.

Comment: "Eclipse gives an error" - what kind of error? And when? During compilation? Validation? Or is it when you execute your program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably importing another `Service` class that is not the spring `@Service` annotation. The FQN is `org.springframework.stereotype.Service`